# Django ORM: Organizing massive amounts of data, the right way

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that uses django-piston to send out XML feeds to internal clients. Generally, these work pretty well but we have some XML feeds that currently run over 15 minutes long. This causes timeouts, and the feeds become unreliable.

I'm trying to ponder ways that I can improve this setup. If it requires some re-structuring of the data, that could be possible too.

Here is how the data collection currently looks:

```
class Data(models.Model)
     # fields

class MetadataItem(models.Model)
     data = models.ForeignKey(Data)

# handlers.py
data = Data.objects.filter(**kwargs)

for d in data:
   for metaitem in d.metadataitem_set.all():
       # There is usually anywhere between 55 - 95 entries in this loop
       label = metaitem.get_label() # does some formatting here
       data_metadata[label] = metaitem.body
```

Obviously, the core of the program is doing much more, but I'm just pointing out where the problem lies. When we have a `data` list of 300 it just becomes unreliable and times out.

What I've tried:

- Getting a collection of all the data id's, then doing a single large query to get all the `MetadataItem`'s. Finally, filtering those in my loop. This was to preserve some queries which it did reduce.
- Using `.values()` to reduce model instance overhead, which did speed it up but not by much.

**One idea** I'm thinking one simpler solution to this is to write to a cache in steps. So to reduce time out; I would write the first 50 data sets, save to cache, adjust some counter, write the next 50, etc. Still need to ponder this.

Hoping someone can help lead me into the right direction with this.

Comment: any chance to restructure your data so that you don't have to run sub-queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the piece of code you posted is that Django doesn't include objects that are connected through a reverse relationship automatically, so you have to make a query for each object. There's a nice way around this, as [Daniel Roseman points out in his blog](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/01/11/django-patterns-part-2-efficient-reverse-lookups/)!

If this doesn't solve your problem well, you could also have a look at trying to get everything in one raw sql query...

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Reduced my queries from n+1 to ... 3 :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe further reduce the query count by first getting all Data id's and then using select_related to get the data and it's metadata in a single big query. This would greatly reduce the number of queries, but the size of the queries might be impractical/too big. Something like:

```
data_ids = Data.objects.filter(**kwargs).values_list('id', flat = True)
for i in data_ids:
    data = Data.objects.get(pk = i).select_related()
    # data.metadataitem_set.all() can now be called without quering the database
    for metaitem in data.metadataitem_set.all():
        # ...
```

However, I would suggest, if possible, to precompute the feeds from somewhere outside the webserver. Maybe you could store the result in memcache if it's smaller than 1 MB. Or you could be one of the cool new kids on the block and store the result in a "NoSQL" database like redis. Or you could just write it to a file on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. unfortunately, I have tried using `select_related` in pretty much the exact same way you described with not much change in speed. There was some improvements, but still a disaster.

Comment: Ok. How about the precomputing approach? Would that be possible given your constraints?

Comment: That's one thing I was thinking of. e.g. setting up celery to queue up changed feeds (they change daily, unfortunately) and process them. I will probably do this anyways, but if there are feeds running over 30 minutes and they are getting changed several times a day, I fear a queue backup.

Comment: If you can precompute a feed faster than it is changing you should be ok. You can also run multiple "workers" in parallell, ie. one worker per feed or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the structure of the data, maybe you can also change the datastore?

The "NoSQL" databases which allow some structure, like CouchDB or MongoDB could actually be useful here.

Let's say for every Data item you have a document. The document would have your normal fields. You would also add a 'metadata' field which is a list of metadata. What about the following datastructure:

```
{
    'id': 'someid',
    'field': 'value',
    'metadata': [
        { 'key': 'value' },
        { 'key': 'value' }
    ]
}
```

You would then be able to easily get to a data record and get all it's metadata. For searching, add indexes to the fields in the 'data' document.

I've worked on a system in Erlang/OTP that used Mnesia which is basically a key-value database with some indexing and helpers. We used nested records heavily to great success.

I added this as a separate answer as it's totally different than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use Celery (www.celeryproject.com) which is a task management system for python and django. You can use it to perform any long running tasks asynchronously without holding up your main app server.